# Como criar eventos dinamicamente? C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, eventos

Estou fazendo um projeto de uma calculadora estatística, nele fiz um método que cria abas em uma tab control e dentro delas uma datagridview para exibir as diferentes tabelas geradas pelo programa.

Preciso de um evento que auto-preenchesse as células da datagrid assim que o usuário entrasse com dois termos.

Estou usando um evento do tipo:

```
private void CalculaPasso(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) //evento de alteração nas celulas
{
    DataGridView dgv = dgvTabela;
    dgvControle.calculaPasso(numeroLinhas, dgv);
    dgvControle.calculaFi(numeroLinhas, dgv);
}

public void calculaPasso(int numeroLinhas, DataGridView dgv)//calcula o passo automaticamente quando a pessoa entra com um valor
{
    //esse comando String.IsNullOrEmpty verifica se a celula está vazia. 
    //Usa-se String.IsNullOrEmpty(Aqui vem a celula, no caso o (string) vai converter o valor da celula em texto

    if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)dgv.Rows[].Cells[1].Value)) | String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)dgv.Rows[].Cells[2].Value))
    {
        dgv.Rows[numeroLinhas].Cells[1].Value = "h = 0";
    }
    else
    {
        double passo = Convert.ToDouble(dgv.Rows[].Cells[2].Value) - Convert.ToDouble(dgv.Rows[].Cells[1].Value);
        dgv.Rows[numeroLinhas].Cells[1].Value = "h = " + passo;

        preencheLimites(passo, numeroLinhas, dgv);
    }
}

public void preencheLimites(double passo, int numeroLinhas, DataGridView dgv)//é chamado pelo método calculaPasso
{
    int i;
    int linhas = numeroLinhas - 1;
    for (i = 1; i < numeroLinhas; i++)
    {
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToDouble(dgv.Rows[i - 1].Cells[1].Value) + passo;
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToDouble(dgv.Rows[i - 1].Cells[2].Value) + passo;
    }
}

public void calculaFi(int numeroLinhas, DataGridView dgv)
{
    int i;
    int Fi = ;

    for (i = ; i < numeroLinhas; i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)dgv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value))
        {
            Fi += ;
        }
        else
            Fi += Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);                                             
    }
    dgv.Rows[numeroLinhas].Cells[3].Value = Fi;  
}
```

Isso funcionava bem quando eu criava apenas uma datagridview no form, mas, agora eu preciso criar as grids conforme o usuário solicita*.

Como crio um evento que veja qual grid foi modificada e assim preencha as células?

*Para criar as datagrids estou fazendo assim:

```
public DataGridView criaTabEDgv(string nome) //chame criaTabEDgv com o nome da tabela a ser criada, por exemplo TDF ou Mtc...
{           
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // primeiro criamos o grid dinamicamente
    var dg = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
    dg.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    dg.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
    dg.Name = "dgv" + nome;
    dg.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
    dg.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

    // adiciona a aba dinamicamente
    var aba = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();            
    aba.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 32);
    aba.Name = "tab" + nome;
    aba.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
    aba.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(638, 300);
    aba.TabIndex = tabControl1.TabCount;
    aba.Text = nome;
    aba.Controls.Add(dg); // adiciona o Grid nesta aba                                 

    // adiciona a tabPage no tabControl1
    tabControl1.Controls.Add(aba);

    return dg;            //retorna a dgv que acabou de ser criada para que outros metodos possam altera-la            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O valor passado ao parâmetro `sender` do método `CalculaPasso()` contém o *Control* que lançou o evento.

Altere o método desta forma:

```
private void CalculaPasso(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Obtem a grid que lançou o evento
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    dgvControle.calculaPasso(numeroLinhas, dgv);
    dgvControle.calculaFi(numeroLinhas, dgv);
}
```

Ao criar a *DataGridView* tem de indicar que é o método `CalculaPasso()` que irá tratar o evento *CellValueChanged*:

```
public DataGridView criaTabEDgv(string nome) //chame criaTabEDgv com o nome da tabela a ser criada, por exemplo TDF ou Mtc...
{           
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // primeiro criamos o grid dinamicamente
    var dg = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
    .......
    .......
    //Regista o método CalculaPasso() para o evento CellValueChanged
    dg.CellValueChanged += CalculaPasso;
    dg.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

    // adiciona a aba dinamicamente
    var aba = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
    .......
    .......
    return dg;            
}
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho, obrigado! Só mais uma coisa... 
Os métodos de dentro do CalculaPasso precisam receber o numeroLinhas que está em outra classe, eu passo esse numero por parâmetro para o construtor dos métodos e ele é repassado para cada método. Como eu passo o numeroLinhas para o calculaPasso se a função que chama ele é a CalculaPasso? Tem como incluir na CalculaPasso outro parâmetro além do sender e da datagrid?

Comment: Infelizmente não. O que é esse numeroLinhas?

Comment: É o número de linhas que a minha datagrid tem, preciso para criar a grid e depois para acessar e alterar a última linha(ela exibe o total de cada coluna).

Comment: `dgv.RowCount` não serve?

Comment: Não... Quando eu repasso esse numero ele buga dizendo 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção.

Consegui criando uma variavel global totalLinhas e em uma das funções que recebem numeroLinhaseu faço totalLinhas = numeroLinhas, eu esperava um modo melhor de lidar com isso, mas foi o único que achei...

Comment: Na classe MeuMenu eu fiz:

public int numeroLinhas
        {
            get { return Convert.ToInt32(txtNumeroLinhas.Text); }            
        }

Funcionou, posso passar numeroLinhas para os métodos, mas, na classe TabControle não consigo acessar a numeroLinhas, mesmo tendo MeuMenu meuMenu = new MeuMenu();
O que está faltando?